# Laravel 5.5 Migration not found on migrate:refresh with --path option

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-migration, eloquent

I am getting **"Migration not found"** when running **migrate:refresh** with **--path** option.

Seems that the script tries to rollback all migrations, not only specified ones.

`php artisan migrate:refresh --path=packages/package/src/database/migrations`

```
Migration not found: 2016_06_01_000005_create_oauth_personal_access_clients_table
Migration not found: 2016_06_01_000004_create_oauth_clients_table
Migration not found: 2016_06_01_000003_create_oauth_refresh_tokens_table
Migration not found: 2016_06_01_000002_create_oauth_access_tokens_table
Migration not found: 2016_06_01_000001_create_oauth_auth_codes_table
Migration not found: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migration not found: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
```

The final result is actually fine. It refreshes the specified folder migrations.

Answer (score 1):

> The migrate:refresh command will roll back all of your migrations and then execute the  migrate command. This command effectively re-creates your entire database:

migrate:refresh will loop through all of the migrations in your migrations table to roll them back.  Since you specified a path, it's looking for all of the migrations in that path.

So essentially it's throwing errors because it can't find those migrations in the path you specified, but it will still work as you expect it because it's rolling back and re-running the migrations it does find.

You normally don't need the path option. Normally, you'd either publish the package's migrations (which copies them to your database/migrations directory) or the package's service provider will define where the migrations can be found.  Refresh expects to rollback ALL the migrations, not specific ones, so while it may work in this example, it's not the intended use.